# Auth0 - Failed to verify code verifier Error

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, auth0, pkce

I'm writing a script which uses auth0 to authenticate with a remote API.

Following this tutorial:
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "strings"
)

func genAuth0CodeVerifierChallance() (string, string) {

    // Generate random Code Verifier
    c := make([]byte, 32)
    rand.Read(c)
    code := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(c)
    code = strings.Replace(code, "+", "-", -1)
    code = strings.Replace(code, "/", "_", -1)
    code = strings.Replace(code, "=", "", -1)

    // Generate auth0 challange
    ch := sha256.Sum256([]byte(code))
    challange := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ch[:])
    challange = strings.Replace(challange, "+", "-", -1)
    challange = strings.Replace(challange, "/", "-", -1)
    challange = strings.Replace(challange, "=", "", -1)

    return code, challange
}
```

I use that function to generate a code challenge, for example `eQM2dqasJN3-gXcM0g1Se-CmAn8PyU7c5uHRKU7Exa0`

I make a HTTP Post with the payload

```
p := &payloadData{
        GrantType:    "authorization_code",
        ClientId:     "...............................", (removed)
        CodeVerifier: codeChallenge, 
        Code:         code, (example: AuL3ArApgQ4QDu_9)
        RedirectUri:  "http://127.0.0.1:16272/oauth/token",
}

...marshal json...

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://my-app.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token", bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
```

I get the error:

{403 Forbidden 403...

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Failed to verify code verifier"}

Other references to this have said characters weren't properly url encoded/replaced in the base64 encoded challenge.

I've tried with the following two encoding's for /

```
code = strings.Replace(code, "+", "-", -1)
code = strings.Replace(code, "/", "_", -1)
code = strings.Replace(code, "=", "", -1)
```

and

```
code = strings.Replace(code, "+", "-", -1)
code = strings.Replace(code, "/", "-", -1)
code = strings.Replace(code, "=", "", -1)
```

But I always get:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Failed to verify code verifier"}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error implementing Auth0 PKCE:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Failed to verify code verifier"}
```

In my case, the error was caused by accidentally sending different Verifiers in the Authorization URL and the Token Exchange. I did some logging of both Authorization URL called and the Token Exchange request body to figure this out and recommend you do the same.

I have a working demo implementation here you can try. This is a HTTP server, not a native app, but it exercises the PKCE flows successfully.

- https://github.com/grokify/oauth2more/blob/master/auth0/examples/auth-code-pkce/main.go

Of note, you don't have to manually replace `+` and `/` since Go supports this using `base64.URLEncoding` instead of `StdEncoding` as follows:

```
strings.Trim(base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(data), "=")
```

In addition to the Auth0 documentation, more information is available on the OAuth 2.0 PKCE in IETF RFC-7636:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636

Comment: I checked the code and the challenges are the same. Also changed to base64 encoding to challange := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(ch[:]) Thanks!